# Received unknown parameters' when trying to update credit card optional details in Stripe

Tags: google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to update the name and expiration date & year of a credit card in Stripe using Firebase Cloud Functions, based on the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/update. Here's my code...

```
exports.updateStripeCard = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log(request.body);
    return cors(request, response, () => {

        stripe.customers.updateSource(
            request.body.customerId,
            request.body.cardId,
            { name: request.body.name
                ,exp_month: request.body.exp_month
                ,exp_year: request.body.exp_year}

        ).then((update) => {
            // asynchronously called
            response.send(update);
            return true;
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
            response.send(err);
            return err;
        });
    })
});
```

When I test it with customerId, cardId, name, month and year, I get the error

```
'Received unknown parameters: name, exp_month, exp_year'
```

I even tried to update just the name, like the example in the documentation, and got a 'Received unknown parameters: name' error.
How on earth can I update the card's name, month and year? Is the syntax incorrect?

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "7.14.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
    "geofire": "^4.1.2",
    "stripe": "^8.39.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: hmmm, I have tested using node.js and it works as expected. which stripe-node version are you using?

Comment: From package.json (added above), using stripe version ^8.39.2. Hope that helps. (Just updated to 8.42.0, same thing)

Comment: @wsw, how did you test it with node.js? I'd like to try it out myself.

Comment: @wsw, I use Cloud Functions to handle the Stripe calls.